# How to convert time-based Javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, datetime, variables

I wrote simple code to declare two **time variables** in javascript ( `NOW` & `CTDR` )

Now I want this code in **PHP** for my other Wordpress Project.

I'm very new to PHP, so I don't know how to convert this to PHP.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var now = new Date().getTime() ;

var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var month = d.getMonth();
var date = d.getDate();
var ctdr = new Date(year, month, date, 14, 13, 00).getTime();

distance = ctdr - now;
```

I tried like below. but getting errors on execution.

**TRIED PHP**

```
$now = date();

$d = new Date();
$year = $d.getFullYear();
$month = $d.getMonth();
$date = $d.getDate();

$d=mktime($year, $month, $date, 14, 13, 00);
```

How to fix this ..?

Comment: How about reading [some documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create) and really try something ..?

Comment: PHP and JS are two different languages with different syntax. Please do some basic research into PHP syntax and working with dates in PHP (there are _thousands_ of guides/tutorials, plus php.net).

Comment: That is not even PHP code!

Comment: "_but getting errors on execution_" is never a good explanation of what went wrong. Always post the exact error message you get

Comment: you have to use php ```strtotime()``` function. Like ```strtotime("now")``` and ```strtotime("Today 14:13:00")```